# Define Bluetooth permissions for a standard Console App in WinRT/C++

Tags: windows, winapi, bluetooth, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm working on a WinRT/C++ application that uses Windows APIs to access to RFCOMM Bluetooth and looks for nearby devices. Then I try to create a service in order to create a connection, so I run:

```
RfcommDeviceService service = RfcommDeviceService::FromIdAsync(currId).get();
```

However, the **FromIdAsync** method returns NULL since, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommdeviceservice.fromidasync?view=winrt-22000#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_Rfcomm_RfcommDeviceService_FromIdAsync_System_String_):

> If a store app has not declared the right capabilities or the user does not grant consent, the method returns a null object.

The solutions I found online all require to add a <Capabilities> tag to the *Package.appxmanifest* file. However, I do not have such file, since I'm working on a standard Console app.

Is there another way to grant permissions to my app? Alternatively, can I include manually a *Package.appxmanifest* file so that I can access the Bluetooth? Or I am completely missing the point here and the error is caused by something else?

**EDIT:** Minimal reproducible example:

```
// Store all the devices
vector<DeviceInformation> devices;
// Replace targetAddress with Bluetooth address to pair
string targetAddress = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX";

// AQS string for RFCOMM devices
hstring selectorString = to_hstring("System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 AND System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}\" AND((System.Devices.Aep.IsPaired: = System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True OR System.Devices.Aep.IsPaired: = System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#False) OR System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.IssueInquiry: = System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#False)");
// Create watcher
DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher(selectorString);

// Callback function for event handling
auto OnAddedDevice = [](DeviceWatcher watcher, DeviceInformation deviceInfo)
{
    devices.push_back(deviceInfo);
};

// New Bluetooth device detected -> callback
deviceWatcher.Added(OnAddedDevice);

// Start watcher
deviceWatcher.Start();
std::cout << "Performing device scan...\n" << endl;

Sleep(4000);

// Stop scanning
deviceWatcher.Stop();

// Print results
for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
    string name = to_string(devices[i].Name());
    string address = getAddress(devices[i]);

    std::cout << "(" << address << ")" << "\t" << name << endl;
}

std::cout << endl;

// Look for target device among the scanned ones
for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
    string address = getAddress(devices[i]);

    // Match found
    if (address == targetAddress) {
        // Get ID
        auto currId = devices[i].Id();

        // Create Service [HERE, FROM IDASYNC RETURNS NULL]
        RfcommDeviceService service = RfcommDeviceService::FromIdAsync(currId).get();

        // Try to get information about the created service [LAUCHES EXCEPTION SINCE service IS NULL]
        auto protectionLevel = service.ProtectionLevel();
    }
}
```

Helper function **getAddress** is used to parse the device ID

```
string getAddress(DeviceInformation device) {
    string id = to_string(device.Id());
    string address = "";
    for (int i = 37; i < id.length(); i++) {
        address += toupper(id[i]);
    }
    return address;
}
```

Comment: The question states, that you are writing a standard console application, but it is tagged with the [tag:uwp] tag as well. Are you writing a UWP Console application or a classic Win32 Console application?

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry. I am writing a classic Win32 Console application. I've now edited the tags

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I've edited the question

Comment: It's difficult to repro the issue without an appropriate BT device to test. Not much help I can offer here, other than a wild guess: I believe the BT API's are bitness-sensitive when used from a non-UWP application. Make sure that your program is compiled for the same bitness as your OS.